# Percentage width in css

Tags: css, width

I have developed a html css code. It works perfect on all browsers but when I am uploading it to the website's sidebar it is not displaying properly.

```
<p>
 <ul style="display:inline; list-style-type: none;">
 <li style="
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 57, 65, 0.9) !important;
 text-decoration:none;

position: relative;
margin: 0 0 -6px 0;

padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;

list-style:none;

width: 100%;

border: 0;

 ">
 <a style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;text-align:center;" href="#">F Awan</a></li>

 <li style="background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 103, 57, 0.9) !important;padding:5px;text-decoration:none;width:95%;text-align:right;color: #000000; text-decoration: none;

 position: relative;

    margin: 0 0 -6px 0;

    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;

    list-style:none;



    border: 0;

 ">(IT Consultant, UK) </li> 
 <li style="background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 218, 57, 0.9) !important;padding:5px;text-decoration:none;color: #000000; text-decoration: none;


 position: relative;

    margin: 0 0 -6px 0;

    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;


    width: 90%;

    border: 0;


 "><a style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;text-align:center;" href="#">FUddin</a> </li> 
 <li style="background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(193, 241, 78, 0.9) !important;padding:5px;text-decoration:none;width:85%;text-align:right;color: #000000; text-decoration: none;

 position: relative;

    margin: 0 0 -6px 0;

    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;

    list-style:none;



    border: 0;

 "> (Systems Engineer, Pakistan)</li> 


 <li style="
 background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(29, 195, 246, 0.9) !important;;padding:5px;
 text-decoration:none;color: #000000; text-decoration: none;

 position: relative;

    margin: 0 0 -6px 0;

    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;

    list-style:none;

    width: 80%;

    border: 0;
    ">

 <a style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none; href="mailto:f_awan@hotmail.com?Subject=Hello%20again">Interact with Us </a>

 </li>
</ul>
</p>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/RN2Hy/) is the JSFiddle.

Comment: wow, inline styles! have you considered that you can use external CSS? and that existing styles in the site CAN affect your sidebar html? and what's wrong with it? you just said *"it is not displaying properly."* - what's not displaying properly? how is it not displaying properly?

Comment: Please migrate all the styles to an external stylesheet, this is a mess.

Comment: @Joseph: I actually was left with no other option except using inline styles for it.

Comment: @Akito you can at least use an internal stylesheet (the one in `<style>` tags)

Comment: @Akito: What's wrong with it? It seems fine to me. By the way, if you ever use this kind of inline stylesheet nightmare again, a demonic rabbit of CSS doom will nag it's way into your server and mess around with those inline stylesheets. Use an external stylesheet: http://jsfiddle.net/5HKmx/2/; *edit* you can even do this in Wordpress (edit your themes).

Comment: @Akito I'm curious, what is the reason you have to use inline styles?  Is it for email? Also, http://premailer.dialect.ca/ This might be handy. By the way, you never say How it should look, only what it currently looks like.

Comment: @Zeta: If you see the image, the width for each of the line should decrease by 5% but it does not decrease on the website(Or I think it is getting displayed larger than 100% so it gets hidden.)

Comment: @Lollero: I want to add this to my wordpress website. I do not know how to make wordpress plugins so this is a hack for it.

Comment: @Akito Oh... Well, I think you mean wordpress themes. The look of your wordpress site is controlled by the current theme and its `style.css` file. Which can be found from `**root**/wp-content/themes/**Current_theme_name**/style.css` All you have to do is add your own css in that file. ( or optionally make another css file and add that to the header.php file also found in the same folder. ) ( although plugin or theme, you can still control the look of it from that same style.css file. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better if you remove `width` & use `margin-right` instead of it. Write like this:

**CSS**

```
.red{
background:rgba(255, 57, 65, 0.9);
}
.orange{
background:rgba(255, 103, 57, 0.9);
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:5%;
}
.yellow{
background:rgba(255, 218, 57, 0.9);
    margin-right:10%;
}
.green{
background:rgba(193, 241, 78, 0.9);
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:15%;
}

.blue{
background:rgba(29, 195, 246, 0.9);
    margin-right:20%;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/RN2Hy/1/

Comment: +1: `margin-right`, of course. I guess I got kind of distracted by the OP's effort (and the inline code) :D.

Comment: Thanks alot. Just needed to remove the padding attribute from the code you provided and it worked very well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common misconception of the box model. If you specify `width:100%` *and* add a `padding` the overall size will be more than 100%.

To prevent this behavior nest another item (e.g. `<div>`) in your list items and use a margin on these.

You could also use `box-sizing: border-box;`, however this is not supported by all browser.

See also:

- [W3C: Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 1 (CSS 2.1) Specification: 8 Box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#box-dimensions)
- [W3C: CSS Positioned Layout Module Level 3: 7. Sizing and positioning details](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#size-and-position-details)
- [MDN: box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing)

Answer (score 1):

You could try CSS3 `box-sizing`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated jsfiddle for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/RN2Hy/8/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/pwvV5/

I inserted an id for the ul so it won't mess up with other ul.
Then added width for it in CSS so it won't overflow.